# Form field attributes in Symfony 2.3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

It was possible in Symfony 2.2 to access form field attributes in template this way:

```
<?php $form['field_name']->get('field_attribute') ?>
```

How can i do this in Symfony 2.3? FormView object doesn't have this function any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit :

Indeed the FormView no longers has `get` function instead you have :

```
array $vars The variables assigned to this view.
```

The similar in twig : `{{ form.task.vars.full_name }}`

The PHP snippet on the documentation seems outdated

Comment: as i said, there is no such method in FormView class. Take a look on http://api.symfony.com/2.3/index.html.